# Installing Ubuntu on laptop via USB gives squashf errors

Tags: error-handling, squashfs

Hey guys my laptop is acer aspire.  I've tried installing Ubuntu on my lap top using USB. I've finished the process and rebooted. Upon reaching my boot up screen I get lots of errors

```
Squashfs error squasfs_read_data failed failed to read block 0x270f3ec0
Squashfs error unable to read fragment cache entry [1b54b5e8]
Squashfs error unable to read page block 1b54b5e8 size 9bc1
```

Answer (score 0):

This normally indicates an error on the media, in this case the USB drive. Maybe there are bad blocks on the device.